# PowerShell & SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, powershell, site-collection

I've recently been appointed the companies admin for SharePoint.  We use SharePoint Online.  As personnel have come and gone they've been able to create their own team-sites.  We apparently have no idea how many sites have been created, where they are and so forth.

Is there a PowerShell command that will allow us to see *every single site and subsite* that exists for our organization.

I also use SharePoint Designer if there is an easier method through that application.

Comment: Here was the return form the PowerShell. I excluded the code you provided for the simplicity of the photo. I just copied and pasted your code into PowerShell though.
[![Here was the return from PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olArN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olArN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SharePoint Online PowerShell, once you have install SPO management shell, you can use the below code:

[Get all site collections and their subsites](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Get-all-collections-and-be30148a#content)
It will prompt for the password twice, then asked for the admin url and admin user name

> Admin url: https:
>   Admin username:

here is the code

```
function Get-SPOAllWeb
{

   param (
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
        [string]$Username,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)]
        $AdminPassword,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=3)]
        [string]$Url
        )
 $ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
  $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $AdminPassword)
  $ctx.Load($ctx.Web.Webs)
  $ctx.Load($ctx.Web)
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

  Write-Host $ctx.Web.Url
  if($ctx.Web.Webs.Count -eq 0)
  {

  }
  else{
  foreach ($web in $ctx.Web.Webs)
  {
    Get-SPOAllWeb -Username $Username -AdminPassword $AdminPassword -Url $web.Url
  }}

}

$passie=Read-Host -Prompt "Password" -AsSecureString
$adminUrelek=Read-Host -Prompt "Admin url"
$adminUserName=Read-Host -Prompt "Admin username" 
Connect-SPOService -Url $adminUrelek -Credential $adminUserName
$sites=(Get-SPOSite).Url



foreach($url in $sites)
{

  Get-SPOAllWeb -Username $adminUserName -AdminPassword $passie -Url $url



}
```

Comment: As far as I understand this will not include the site collections created via Teams or Groups, right?

Answer (score 1):

For all webs you can use the PNP library: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url https://yoursite.sharepoint.com –Credentials (Get-Credential)
Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse
```

For Site Collections...
You can use the SharePoint Online PowerShell cmdlet Get-SPOSite

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/get-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps

Download here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588

You will need to be a Tenant Admin.

```
Connect-SPOService https://YourDomain-admin.sharepoint.com
Get-SPOSite
```

To stay in the SPO cmdlets and not use PNP see: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Script-to-get-All-Webs-in-c2c1cdaf

SharePoint Designer can only look at one site at a time.

Comment: So the return when I run the command is this:

Run "Connect-SPOService" first.

I run that and it asks for the URL, which I type in for both the corporate SharePoint landing page.  https://xxx.SharePoint.com.  It tells me the following:

Current site is not a tenant administration site.

So I try to run it for the specific site I need to see all sub-sites for and it tells me that it cannot authenticate to SharePoint Online using OAuth 2.0.

Comment: Yes, as in the sample above.